# Does Kotlin supports AIDL?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, aidl

I have a simple AIDL definition and I want to use in Kotlin code but when it builds shows Unresolved reference error for all variables that uses the interface. but the same AIDL has no problem in Java code. does Kotlin support it? how to solve
here my AIDL in src/main/aidl/

```java
// ServiceInterface.aidl
package com.example.test;

interface ServiceInterface {
    void test(String arg1);
}
```

and activity code is

```java
import android.content.ComponentName
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.ServiceConnection
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.IBinder
import android.os.RemoteException
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.swiftytime.clientappcommunication.R
import com.example.test.ServiceInterface

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var mServiceAidl: ServiceInterface? = null
    var mIsBound = false

    private val mConnection: ServiceConnection = object : ServiceConnection {
        override fun onServiceConnected(className: ComponentName, service: IBinder) {
            try {
                mServiceAidl = ServiceInterface.Stub.asInterface(service)
                Log.e("app", "Attached")
            } catch (e: RemoteException) {

            }
        }

        override fun onServiceDisconnected(className: ComponentName) {
            mServiceAidl = null
            Log.e("app", "Disconnected.")
        }
    }

    private fun doBindService() {
        val intent = Intent().apply {
            component = ComponentName(
                "com.example.test", "com.example.test.MyService"
            )
        }
        bindService(
            intent,
            mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE
        )
        mIsBound = true
        Log.e("app", "Binding.")
    }

    private fun doUnbindService() {
        if (mIsBound) {
            unbindService(mConnection)
            mIsBound = false
            Log.e("app", "Unbinding.")
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        doBindService()
    }
}
```

this is error

```
[ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Task] e: /Volumes/Projects/AndroidProject/ClientAppCommunication/app/src/main/java/com/example/test/MainActivity.kt: (16, 23): Unresolved reference: ServiceInterface
```

Answer (score 3):

After many hours, I found the problem which is buildToolsVersion 29.0.0 generate wrong path for generated java files, I submitted a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145596078)

Just changing to buildToolsVersion 28.0.3 solve the issue.

**Update:**
Problem Solved and now it works in `buildToolsVersion 29.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using AIDL with Kotlin and what I have is interfaces written in Java and all model classes that are used by defined interfaces are written in Kotlin and it is working perfectly.
For example. I have I*Subscriber.aidl with method

```
void onSomeEventHappened(in AidlEvent event);
```

and also I have the .aidl file and .kt file for AidlEvent class.

AidlEvent.aidl file

```
// AidlEvent.aidl

parcelable AidlEvent;
```

AidlEvent.kt

```
data class AidlEvent(
    val eventType: Int,
    val eventMessage: String):
        Parcelable {
    // add parcelable methods
}
```

I'm not sure that you will be able to write .aidl interface in Kotlin, haven't managed to do that. It should not be an issue if you need to write few methods in Java, as you don't need to implement them in Java, you will just declare them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have not problem regarding to define interfaces in java and all other things. My problem is that I can't use in Kotlin code. for example when calling this ```ServiceInterface.Stub.asInterface(service)``` the IDE has not showing any problem but when building the app it said the Unresolved reference: ServiceInterface.
please could share how you initialize your service in Kotlin code.
Thanks